# MVC3 Models & Complex Relationships

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, models, relationships, navigation-properties

Lets say you have the following models:

```
public class Dog {
  public int DogId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Cat {
  public int CatId { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

// This model/table allows us to link multiple colors to an animal
// Lets say type of 1 is dog, 2 is cat for simplicity
public class AnimalColor {
  public int ObjectId { get; set; }
  public int TypeId { get; set; }
  public virtual Color Color { get; set; }
}

public class Color {
  public int ColorId { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

The problem with this architecture is that AnimalColor is technically a navigation property of both Dog and Cat, but the complexity of it stops you from being able to use the "built in" features like the relationship between AnimalColor and Color.

The relationship between Dog and AnimalColor has a condition of TypeId, not to mention the ForeignKey won't properly work because the key names aren't the same (DogId and ObjectId).

My question is this: am I totally missing something that makes this work? If not, what's the best way to handle this type of situation if I want to pull a list of Dogs with the AnimalColors as a property?

Currently the only solution I have for this is to pull two lists and grab the colors as I loop through the Dogs. Seems like there should be a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from your question, I would write like this"

```
public class Animal {
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public List<Color> Colors { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Dog : Animal { }

public class Cat : Animal { }
```

This way you don't need `TypeId`, you can verify the type like this:

```
Cat a = new Cat();
Dog b = new Dog();
Animal c = new Dog();
if (a is Cat) {...}  // true
if (b is Dog) {...}  // true
if (c is Dog) {...}  // true
```

if you have more mulyiple colors:

```
a.Colors.Add(new Color(255, 255, 255));
a.Colors.Add(new Color(100, 100, 0));
```

But I'm not 100% sure if that was your problem.